# How do I send a variable from nodejs to all the connected clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm currently working on a project for school, my idea is to create a roulette game with a chat, so I'm working with nodejs and socket IO my question is how do I send the value of the random number generated in the server to all my clients and then execute the javascript function to spin the roulette?

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var debug = require('debug')('workspace:server');
var http = require('http');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var session = require('express-session')({
    secret: "secret",
    key: 'secret.sid',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
});
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();

var openid = require('openid');

var app = express();

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.Server(app);

var socket = require('socket.io')(server);
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
        console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
        console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
        default:
        throw error;
    }
}

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session);

function createRelyingParty(req) {
    var baseUrl = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");
    return new openid.RelyingParty(baseUrl + "/verify", baseUrl, true, false, []);
}

// for every request lets make the user session available to the templates
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Roulette',
        session: (typeof req.session.user !== 'undefined') ? req.session.user : ''
    });
});

socket.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});
});
socket.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    socket.emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
});
});

var r = require('./SpinGen');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```

SpinGen.js (js to generate and send the number to the client)

```
    var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(server);

setInterval(function() {

    var rndNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 34) + 0);

    var winningNum = rndNum;
    console.log(winningNum);
    socket.emit('roulette', winningNum);
},10000);
```

client-side.js

```
      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
  socket.on('roulette', function(spin){
    spinTo(spin);
  });
  socket.on('error', function(evData){
    console.error('Connection Error:',evData);
  });
```

Comment: I suggest you look at Meteor ( its a framework built on top of Node).  It's designed to make this kind of thing REALLY simple

Comment: I messed up the code -.-

Comment: @KeithNicholas I fixed the code, sorry for the messup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would send (emit) the random number to all connected clients - it would look something like this:

```
io.emit('random number', randomNumber);
```

You would then listen for the event on the client side like so:

```
socket.on('random number', function(num){
    // num contains the random number

    // spin the wheel to the random number
   spinTo(num)
  });
```

Comment: If this doesn't work - try socket.emit('random number', randomNumber); inside on of your 'socket.on' / 'io.on'... blocks.

Comment: Then I can only think it's to do with your structure, as someone mention above - it looks like you're creating two separate instances of express/socket. If you put the code in app.js does it work then?

Comment: I tried adding this to my app.js

var r = require('./SpinGen');
var number = r.rndNum;
socket.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('random number', function(number){
    socket.emit('random number', number);
    console.log('number: ' + number);
});
});

and this to spingen.js

    setInterval(function() {

        var rndNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 34) + 0);
        exports.rndNum= rndNum;
    },10000);

still not working...

Comment: That wont work as r.rndNum will be undefined (you didn't export the random number).

Comment: on spingen.js i added this exports.rndNum= rndNum;

Comment: Try changing the 'socket.on('connection'... part to: (in app.js)


socket.on('connection', function(socket){
   var rndNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 34) + 0);
        socket.emit('random number', rndNum);
});  As your example above was waiting for the random number event before it emitted it's own random number event.

Comment: Try adding it into an setInterval as you did in spingen.js e.g: 

socket.on('connection', function(socket){
   var rndNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 34) + 0);
  
    setInterval(function() {
        socket.emit('random number', rndNum);
    },10000);
});

Just a warning, this will generate a unique random number for each connected client (I'm not sure if that's what you want) - if not, it's worth creating a new question about keeping a set state between multiple connections,

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work, doesn't even spin once

Comment: humm no... thats not what I want I want the same number for every client

Comment: As I said, that is a completely different question (about keeping a shared state between multiple socket clients). I'm not sure why the set Interval isn't working as you said.

Comment: I solved it... I removed the socket.on('connection'.... now it's just this and it works

setInterval(function() {
    var rndNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 34) + 0); 
    socket.emit('random number', rndNum); 
    console.log(rndNum);
}, 8000);

Comment: That's good to hear, if you need help keeping a set state for multiple clients I suggest you create a new question as suggested above. If my answers have helped solve the problem please mark the solution as correct.

Comment: already did, thank you :)

p.s - I'll post a new question for the set state

Answer (score 1):

Try using `io.sockets.emit` instead of `socket.emit`. That will emit to all connected clients

Comment: You are creating two sockets in app.js and spingen.js. Probably they start on different adress, so try to io.socket.emit in app.js.

Comment: I must use exports.rndNum = rndNum; on spingen.js and r.rndNum on app.js right? I'm kind of new to javascript

Comment: Yes. And dont forget to var spin = require("./spingen");